# Gitlab Omnibus memory leak

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-omnibus

I have installed Gitlab Omnibus v11.1.0 (35c387c) in Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS. Looking at htop output on my server I see memory consumption swapping in 100%. My configuration of gitlab.rb:

sidekiq['concurrency'] = 5

unicorn['worker_processes'] = 1

postgresql['shared_buffers'] = "1GB"

[Screenshot htop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2YZu.png)

Is there any way to fix this ?

Comment: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues